# Check if the User Id stored in an object in an array is equal to the Id of the Authenticated user

Tags: javascript

Here's the structure of the array:

```
post: [
   comments: {
        userId: 123123123,
        name: John doe
             }
      ]
```

I want to check if the authenticated user's Id (auth.user.id) exists in any of the the comments stored in the Post array. I want to return a boolean as a result.

I have tried using the find() method and the includes() method but haven't had success.

Comment: Welcome to SO this page might assist you to getting started [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
posts.filter(comments => comments.userId === auth.user.id).length !== 0
```

this expression will evaluate to true if the user id exists in the posts comments , and evaluate to false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
post: [
  comments: {
    userId: 123123123,
    name: John doe
  }
]
```

its not valid.

it should be this

```
 post : [{
   comments : {
     userId: 123123123,
     name: 'John doe'
   }
 }]
```

or this

```
post: [
  {
     userId: 123123123,
     name: John doe
   }
]
```

```js
     var post = [{
         comments : {
           userId: 123123123,
           name: 'John doe'
         }
    }]
          
    console.log(post);
          
    var f = userId => post.some(x => x.comments.userId == userId);

    console.log(f(123123123))
```